# How do I turn off scheduled server publishing in Tableau Desktop (9.1)?

Tags: tableau-api

I have some reports that publish daily to a Tableau server.

I can see easily how to setup a new publishing schedule for the reports from `Server -> Publish Workbook...`, but I cannot find anywhere to turn current publishing off.

I have searched all over and cannot find the answer.  How do I turn off the currently scheduled publishing for the workbook?  Does it have to be turned off on the server?

Thank you!

Comment: Automated publishing of workbooks to server sounds like a custom script of some sort. I have never seen the ability to do this from tableau server software itself. Can you trace which account is doing the publishing?

Comment: I researched a little more and it's not actually republishing itself, just updating the data every day.  I found I could turn this on the server side, not on Desktop.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was not using the right terminology.  I published the workbook and it does not re-publish.  However, the data source refreshes from the server and that is what I wanted to turn off.

Unless I republished the workbook with a different data refresh setting, changing the data refresh settings has to be done on the Tableau Server client, not Tableau Desktop.

On the Tableau Server client, the main navbar has a "Scheduling" tab.  This lists all scheduled tasks, including times and frequencies for certain data refreshes.

To configure a workbook's data refresh, the "Refresh Schedule" tab in the workbook controls the data refresh.

So to adjust a reports data refreshing, that is done on the server or by republishing the report with different data refresh settings.